# How can I implement logs in Worker Service .NET Core for Linux

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core

I am working on .NET Core 3.1 new `Worker Service` project template for `Linux` service. I want to implement logging for Linux.

I have to generate a `text` file and logs in that file. I have tried something but that is not generating any file for `Linux daemon`.

`Program class` code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.File(@"F:\Logs\Worker\logfile.txt").CreateLogger(); //On this location folder and file will be created

    IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
    {
        scheduler
          .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
          .EveryThirtySeconds();
    });
    host.Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSystemd()

.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddScheduler();
    services.AddTransient<ReprocessInvocable>();
}).UseSerilog();
```

`ReprocessInvocable.cs` class code which calls from `Main`

```
public async Task Invoke()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Information - Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    _logger.LogWarning("Warning - Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    _logger.LogError("Error - Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);;
    Log.Information("Invoke has called at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    //return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

How can I make it work for `Linux` executable? or existing code should work fine?

**Edit 1:**

1)What are you using to run your daemon? supervisord? systemd?

I have used Systemd to install daemon.

2)Do you have expectations for what you want out of "logging on Linux"?

I want to generate a text file when daemon start(this is quite easy in windows :)) and log/write the text like Method1 called at {time} and Method2 called at {time} etc.. Just to track the flow of service.

3)Do you want a log file on disk?

For Linux, I want to log in Linux machine storage.

4)Or a log that goes into the system logs?

If that is giving me a file with excepted log then it will also be ok.

Comment: What are you using to run your daemon? `supervisord`? `systemd`? or something else? Do you have expectations for what you want out of "logging on Linux"? Do you want a log file on disk? Or a log that goes into the system logs? The path `@"F:\Logs\Worker\logfile.txt"` obviously makes no sense on Linux.

Comment: @omajid - Could you please check edit1 in the question, I tried to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If simply writing to a Linux system log (the one at `/var/log/syslog`) is a suitable solution for you, then you can simply do this:

```
[DllImport("libc")]
private static extern void syslog(int priority, string message);
```

And use it to log to `syslog` storage.

I wrote a very simple `"syslog.h"` wrapper for C# and published here as a gist: https://github.com/jitbit/SyslogCore Just include one short `.cs` file in your project and then use:

```
Syslog.Write(Syslog.Level.Warning, "My service name", "something went wrong");
```